# Set custom space for UICollectionViewCell for every rows

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I build ViewController with UiCollectionView, and I created my custom View to display in every cell.
This is the code on my controller to display, resize the cell.
I need to have 3 cell for every row in UiCollectionView

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var listaCategorie = [CategoryModel]()
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.listaCategorie.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

         let noOfCellsInRow = 3

         let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
         let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
             + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
            + 30
             + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))
         let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 130)
     }

    // UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let cellWidthPadding = collectionView.frame.size.width / 30
        let cellHeightPadding = collectionView.frame.size.height / 4
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: cellHeightPadding,left: cellWidthPadding, bottom: cellHeightPadding,right: cellWidthPadding)
    }
    
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        var category = self.listaCategorie[indexPath.row];
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cella", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellViewsCategories
         
         var puntoLuce = self.listaCategorie[indexPath.row];
         
        cell.labelCategoryName.text = puntoLuce.description
        //cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "light-bulb-2.png");
         cell.backgroundColor = getUIColorFromRGBThreeIntegers(red: 63,green: 162,blue: 217);
         cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6
         cell.layer.masksToBounds = false;
         cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
         cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
         cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
       

        
        //RECUPERO LA DIMENSIONE
        let noOfCellsInRow = 4

        //FINE RECUPERO DIMENSIONE
        
        
        if(puntoLuce.imageUrl != ""){
            let imageUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: puntoLuce.imageUrl!)!
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl as URL)!
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    cell.imageCategory.image = image
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func getUIColorFromRGBThreeIntegers(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(Float(red) / 255.0),
                       green: CGFloat(Float(green) / 255.0),
                       blue: CGFloat(Float(blue) / 255.0),
                       alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.title = "ARRIVA ARRIVA"
        //on click su label temp
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.tapFunction))
        getCategoryList()
        collectionView.delegate = self // Unless you have already defined the delegate in IB
        collectionView.dataSource = self // Unless you have already defined the dataSource in IB
        self.collectionView.frame = self.collectionView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }
    
    @objc func tapFunction() {
           // handle label tap here
           print("click");
       }
    
    func getCategoryList(){
        var params = [
            "" : ""
        ]
        let postUrl = APIRequest(endPoint: "category_list")
        postUrl.sendRequest(parameters: params as! [String : String]) {
            responseObject, error in
            let user = CategoryModel(id: "0",
            description: "Tutti",
            imageUrl: "")
            self.listaCategorie.append(user)
            guard let responseObject = responseObject, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            do{
                let messageData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseCategoryModel.self, from: responseObject)
                var array = messageData.result
                for categoryModel in array {
                    let user = CategoryModel(id: "",
                                             description: categoryModel.categoryName,
                                             imageUrl: categoryModel.image)
                    self.listaCategorie.append(user)
                }
                print(array.count);
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }catch{
                print("errore durante la decodifica dei dati")
            }
    }
}
```

But this is the result:

[image]

As you can see from the photo there is too space from the 3 cells. There is a way to set minus space by cells?

**EDIT**
I try to use the code on first response. THis is the result
[image]

Comment: Why don't you select the collection view and see what's available under the Size Inspector?

Comment: on vievDidLoad() method I write this code: "let size = collectionView.contentSize;" but size is width = 0 and height = 0

Comment: In sizeForItemAt / 3 - 5. you will get a good result, remove others go step by step

Comment: I write the follow code, "let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow) - 5)
        return CGSize(width: size, height: 130)"
but the result is the same, I need to specific the space between cell. I need to display 3 cells in the same row

Comment: You're setting up things relating to size in viewDidLoad, at this point the view controller's view isn't necessarily the size it will end up at on the screen. Do you have to use flow layout or would you be happy with an answer using compositional layouts?

Comment: ok thanks for the response. How can I change my code to fix this issue?

Comment: If you want three cells per row, what height should they be? Are you looking to make the cells wider or narrower or just change the spacing?

Comment: The heigh can be fixed to 130. I need to have 3 cells for row. As you can see from the last print screen the last cell is out of the screen. I need to decrease the space between cells.

Comment: @bircastri make sure "Estimate Size" for the collection view is set to `None`, in the storyboard size inspector

Comment: @aheze yes I m check but I set NONE ase estimate size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` will give you a layout that automatically adjusts to the collection view size. Remove all code you have relating to the flow layout and create a compositional layout in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Cell will be the full height of the enclosing group
let cellHeight = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalHeight(1)
// Cell will be 1/3 width of the enclosing group
let cellWidth = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(0.333)
// The size of the cell
let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: cellWidth, heightDimension: cellHeight)
// This item represents a single cell
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
// The cell will be inset by these distances within the item
item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

// The group will be a fixed height
let groupHeight = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.absolute(130)
// The group will occupy the full available width
let groupWidth = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1)
// The group will repeat to hold as many of the cells as it can in a horizontal row before wrapping
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: groupWidth, heightDimension: groupHeight), subitems: [item])

// The actual section, which consists of a single group
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
// The insets of the group from the edge of the collection view
section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

// Create and assign the layout
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

I've tried to break it up into chunks so it makes sense, these layouts can take some time to wrap your head around.

It gives you the following portrait layout:

[image]

And in landscape:

[image]

If you want a fixed cell size, then use `.absoluteWidth` for the cell width, and add an `interItemSpacing` of `.flexible` to the group.

Using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` you can achieve a very similar result with less code than you have in your question. With a plain project, the only collection view related code I had was this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.sectionInset = .init(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Then this single flow layout delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var width = (collectionView.bounds.width - 20) / 3
    width -= 10
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 130)
}
```

This gives you three columns per row in portrait or landscape.

Comment: Your code are working correctly, but I need to insert this code on my class:@available(iOS 13.0, *), now my application should be available also for ios < ios 13.0. I think that this code works only for iOS 13

Comment: Yes, this is iOS 13+ only, sorry.

Comment: Your solution are working, there is a Way to fix this also for previous verson of iOS?

Comment: You need to adjust your layout every time the collection view's bounds size changes. But a quick question - do you really want a collection view here, if you just want three things that fit on the width of the screen then a stack view is probably a better solution.

Comment: @bircastri I added an example using flow layout

Answer (score 0):

Add the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate and add these methods and update your values according to your requirement like:-

```
let edge    : CGFloat = 10.0
let spacing : CGFloat = 10.0
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let noOfColumn = 3
    let collectionviewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
    let bothEdge =  CGFloat(edge + edge) // left + right
    let excludingEdge = collectionviewWidth - bothEdge
    let cellWidthExcludingSpaces = excludingEdge - ((noOfColumn-1) * spacing)
    let finalCellWidth = cellWidthExcludingSpaces / noOfColumn
    let height = finalCellWidth
    return CGSize(width: finalCellWidth, height: height)
}
```

Comment: I try to use your code. but this is the result:
I add the new print screen on my original question.